# How can I use sunlight to heat a RBF and reflux a reaction?

Tags: thermodynamics, experimental-chemistry, heat, temperature

This may seem like a off topic question but I really need help on it. I am currently working on a polymerization reaction in which I'm breaking down plastic polymers into smaller molecules. However, since this is a green chemistry project, I decided, with the suggestion of other chemists, that I should a method that doesn't require a lot of electrical energy to heat it. One idea was an enzyme, but I decided I want to use solar energy to reflux the RBF. I have a few ideas and please comment on them and also provide your own suggestions:

- First is using a parabolic mirror below the flask to focus the heat towards it.
- Second idea is painting the RBF black and hoping that is sufficient to heat it to reflux.

Comment: How about buying solar panels and connecting them to a nice electrical heater?

Comment: @Jori It sounds like a nice idea but converting sunlight to electrical energy and then to heat isn't actually that efficient (mainly inefficiency of the solar panel). On the other hand, parabolic mirrors and/or black surfaces can be pretty effective. You are probably looking for something along the lines of [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solar_cooker).

Comment: If you get good sunlight, the idea provided by @bon can be done with very simple materials, i.e. some cardboard and the shiny side of a piece of aluminum foil.

Comment: Thanks everyone. I love the solar heater idea. I talked to my professor and we will try to build our own next week. If it doesn't heat enough, then I will buy this [solar cooker](http://www.ebay.com/itm/New-Copenhagen-Solar-Cooker-Oven-Stove-Normal-OvenTemps-All-Day-All-Year-/351434376342?pt=LH_DefaultDomain_0&hash=item51d31f0496). ITs suppose to reach up to 230 C